# Kivy Recycleview. How to use it?

Tags: kivy

I want to know about Kivy Recycle view. How to use it? I want to see a an answer like widget description in documentation. I know in github there is an short description. This is not enough. So can someone explain how to use the Recycleview widget and what are its properties, what are events?

Comment: Are you still looking at RecycleView?  I'm trying to understand it too...

In regard to @Hellboy's comment, kivy's freenode channel (#kivy) is a good place for questions.

Comment: kivy has deprecated recycleview from kivy-garden and has been added to standard kivy documentation (version 1.9.2). Please check [this](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecycleView is a garden widget

to use garden widgets you do::

```
pip install kivy-garden
cd to/your/app/folder
garden install <WidgetName>
```

Then you simply use the widget using from kivy.garden import

Documentation is here http://kivy-garden.github.io

Documentation for each garden widget is on it's github page https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.recycleview

Comment: [`kivy.uix.recycleview` is added in kivy 1.10.0](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)

Answer (score -2):

Kivy Recycleview has not yet covered in their standard documentation. So I guess you need to wait a bit. Alternatively you can ask question to their irc #kivy. It seems Kivy is not popular framework so very few guys are active in Stack over flow to answer your question.

Comment: qua-non asked a question (although broad).  You essentially told him you did not know the answer and then expressed your opinion about the popularity of the framework.  This is why I do not think your answer was helpful.