# kivy.uix.recycleview Import Error

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am getting this error on importing the kivy `recycleview` module.

> from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
>    ImportError: No module named 'kivy.uix.recycleview'

My kivy version is 1.9.1 (python 3.4)
I already referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33122529/5465739) answer, but the [github page](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.recycleview) mentions that the package is deprecated from kivy-garden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecycleView is added to Kivy 1.9.2 but it is still in development phase.

So I think you must use kivy-garden or upgrade to Kivy 1.9.2 (dev) to use RecycleView module.